# vue3 responsive problem by use reference data

Tags: vuejs3

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div class="lockcontent" v-show="lock.length">
      Lock :
      <template v-for="(item2) in lock">
        <div class="container">
          <span>{{ item2.name }}</span>
        </div>
      </template>
    </div>
    <button @click="handleLockData"> Add</button>
  </div>

</template>
<script setup lang="ts">

const lock = ref<any[]>([])

const newarr =[1,2,3,4]

const handleLockData = () => {
  newarr.push(Math.random())
  lock.value = newarr
}
</script>
```

**as you can see,when i use this ways to push a random value to the newarr,then i
assignment the newarr to the lock.value,when i click this button the first time , the page can update and show me update value ,but the second time ,third time and more ,the page can't update ,why?**

i try to debug and saw source code,i find if i use those way to add some value to the non-responsive variable，the will not into **nexttick** in source code , but i don't know why,may be i guest problems caused by reference data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `lock` is basically `lock: {value: Reactive<any[]> }`

The first time you change it's `value` from `ar1 = []` to `ar2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`

then you've pushed into non-reactive `ar2`

The second time you change it's `value` from `ar2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]` to `ar2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]`. It's the same object so it ignores the change.

You need to use `lock` directly to obrain `Reactive<ar2>`

```
lock.value.push(Math.random())
```

Comment: so it is a reference type data cause this problems，right？the second until  more the  `lock.value` point to the same memory address

Comment: It's more that it was not `Reactive`. If you would say `var newarr =reactive([1,2,3,4]); var lock = newarr` it would work fine WITHOUT any `lock` needed. `Ref` basically make this thing - if you get `.value` you get `Reactive` under the hood

Comment: Templates internally get `.value` of refs, to make you able to use both `ref` and `reactive` the exactly same way (only in templates)